# Cache size on heroku postgres smaller than advertised?

Tags: heroku

I fired up a Zilla instance of heroku postgres which is advertised as having 17GB of memory cache.

When I run show all; I see:
effective_cache_size               | 12240000kB

Does this mean the cache is 12GB and not 17GB? Or am I missing something? Queries run much slower when my dataset goes above the 12GB point.

Comment: I also see this: shared_buffers | 3320MB

Comment: "Heroku Postgres plans vary primarily by the size of their in-memory data cache. The quoted cache size constitutes the total amount of RAM given to Postgres. While a small amount RAM is used for managing each connection and other tasks, Postgres will take advantage of almost all this RAM for its cache." https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cache-size

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit on the available memory on the underlying hardware (17G for a zilla). This amount of memory cannot be used entirely for the "hot dataset" cache, however. Many other aspects of normal postgres operations also require memory, as you may imagine. Some of that includes establishing a connection (which spawns a backend), queries requiring joins, queries requiring sorts, or aggregates like count, sum, max, etc. Additionally, processes such as autovacuum also use part of that available memory.

Comment: Given all the trouble had recently with not representing their routing infrastructure accurately in documentation (RapGenius story), I think heroku does need to change the pricing page  https://postgres.heroku.com/pricing. The page says "7.5GB cache", but deeper reading of the docs show this is just not the case. Part of that ram is used for the OS and postgres. If they are selling cache size, they should advertise cache size and not total memory.

Comment: Hi @saintsjd, we're working on a Dev Center article to clarify this. Our team would like to connect with you directly to get your feedback. Can you drop an email to harold@heroku.com?

Comment: Heroku team reached out to me and was very responsive to my questions. They have made some revisions to the pricing page and docs which I find very helpful. The inner workings of the postgresql cache make a bit more sense now. https://postgres.heroku.com/pricing